# jsf rich:message not displaying error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am developing a JSF site and am struggling with error messages. I want to display messages in two places. One should be a global error message to catch all (this works) and the other should catch messages for a specific input... this is where I am having problems. Here is my form:

```
<h:form class="form" id="homeInfo">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="#{HomeBean.hasResults ? 'disabled': ''}">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="multi-line">
            <legend>#{homeBean.homeIdLable}</legend>
            <h:inputText id="homeId" value="#{homeBean.homeId}" placeholder="Optional"
                         styleClass="#{HomeBean.hasResults ? 'disabled': 'required'}"/>
            <rich:message for="homeId" styleClass="inline-error" />
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <a4j:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" styleClass="ui-btn-up-undefined ui-btn"
                           action="#{homeController.matchHomeId(HomeBean.vin)}"
                           disabled="#{homeBean.hasResults}"
                           render="#{empty facesContext.messageList ? 'homeList':''}"
                           onbegin="displayBusy()"
                           oncomplete="displayBusy('', true); matchHomeId(#{homeBean.hasResults});"/>
        <br/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

And here is my logic in the controller that throws the error on an invalid homeId:

```
public void matchHomeId(String homeId) {
    if (validHomeId) {
        do logic ....
    } else {
        getFacesContext().addMessage("homeInfo:homeId",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The home ID you entered is not valid.", "The home ID you entered is not valid."));
    }
}
```

Everything I read says that the component id for the message should be : which is why I use homeInfo:homeId for my error message. However, I have also tried just homeId. If I change from `<rich:message ... />` to `<rich:messages ... />` I see my error just fine, however then I get all the global error messages for the page, which is not what I want. What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding `ajaxRendered="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to everything else I read out there which says the client id should be `<formId>:<inputId>` or `homeInfo:homeId` this did not work. I tried this approach which did work:

```
private UIComponent component;

public UIComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}

public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
    this.component = component;
}
```

I then bound the input to the component and then passed in `component.getClientId()` to the error and that worked. In the debugger I noticed that the id being passed in was `homeId`. However if I hardcoded `homeId` for the clientId that did not work. Finally I noticed that on a regular validation error everything worked fine. HOWEVER, the id that was being used is `homeInfo-homeId`. So long story shorter... the client id passed in should be `<formId>-<inputId>`

```
public void matchHomeId(String homeId) {
    if (validHomeId) {
        do logic ....
    } else {
        getFacesContext().addMessage("homeInfo-homeId",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The home ID you entered is not valid.", "The home ID you entered is not valid."));
    }
}
```